# Record screen and save video to server in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code that uses ReplayKit to record the screen, and saves it in the documents Directory of the app. The problem comes when I am trying to access it, it does not find the URL of the video.

```
import SwiftUI
import ReplayKit
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var screenRecording = ScreenRecording.singleton
    @State var buttonMessage: String = "Start recording"
    @State var showVideo: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(buttonMessage) {
            if screenRecording.recording {
                screenRecording.stopRecording()
                buttonMessage = "Start recording"
            } else {
                screenRecording.startRecording()
                buttonMessage = "Stop recording"
            }
            screenRecording.recording = !screenRecording.recording
        }
        Button("next screen") {
            showVideo = true
        }
        if showVideo {
            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: screenRecording.getDocument()))
                .frame(height: 400)
                .onAppear {
                    print("URL: \(screenRecording.getDocument().path)")
                }
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}



class ScreenRecording: ObservableObject {
    var recording: Bool = false
    private let screenRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    
    static let singleton = ScreenRecording()
    private init() {}
    
    func startRecording() {
        if !screenRecorder.isRecording && RPScreenRecorder.shared().isAvailable {
            screenRecorder.isMicrophoneEnabled = true
            screenRecorder.isCameraEnabled = true
            screenRecorder.startRecording { err in
                guard err == nil else {
                    print("Failed to start recording...")
                    return
                }
                print("Recording starts!")
            }
        } else {
            print("Trying to start recording when a recording is already happening!")
        }
    }
    
    func stopRecording() {
        if screenRecorder.isRecording {
            screenRecorder.stopRecording(withOutput: getDocumentDirectoryURL()) { err in
                guard err == nil else {
                    print("An error has ocurred: \(String(describing: err))")
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Recording stops!")
        } else {
            print("Trying to stop recording when NO recording is initiated!")
        }
    }
    
    func getDocumentDirectoryURL() -> URL {
        let documentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        
        print("Filepath is: \(documentDirURL.path)")
        return documentDirURL
    }
    
    func getDocument() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        print("This re the paths: \(paths)")
        return paths[0]
    }
}
```

The method `getDocument` should return the first URL of the directory, which should be the video file, but it does not work. Where is the problem?

Comment: What are you doing with 'screenRecording.getDocument().path' and how are you using it?  What is the actual path of the video to which to write a video clip?

Comment: The path is being generated in the `getDocument()` method, since we get all the paths and return the first one found, which should be the one with the video since there is no more files in that directory.

Comment: your getDocument and getDocumentDirectoryURL functions are the same. FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) is returning you the path(s) to the document directory itself, not the files in it. see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407726-urls

Comment: @Shadowrun I don't think they are (exactly) the same, they do indeed return the same, but `getDocumentDirectoryURL()` gets the path to the directory, and `getDocument()` gets all the paths available, and then return the first one (which is the one for the directory). But how can I then have the path to the video file?

Comment: see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager the "Discovering Directory Contents" section.   FileManager's urls(for:in:) is used to locate standard system directories like "the documents folder", once you have that documents directory URL, then pass that URL to one of the methods described in "Discovering Directory Contents"

Comment: I went manually to the location of the URL in my local machine, and there is nothing there. It does not create the video and save it in the URL given.... why?

Comment: Think about why I asked those questions.  If you read those question carefully, you'll find the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Apple's demo

[Recording and Streaming Your macOS App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/recording_and_streaming_your_macos_app)

The relevant code is

```
     func exportClip() {
        let clipURL = getDirectory()
        let interval = TimeInterval(5)
    
        print("Generating clip at URL: ", clipURL)
        RPScreenRecorder.shared().exportClip(to: clipURL, duration: interval) { error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error attempting to start Clip Buffering")
            } else {
                // There isn't an error, so save the clip at the URL to Photos.
                self.saveToPhotos(tempURL: clipURL)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getDirectory() -> URL {
        var tempPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"
        let stringDate = formatter.string(from: Date())
        print(stringDate)
        tempPath.appendPathComponent(String.localizedStringWithFormat("output-%@.mp4", stringDate))
        return tempPath
    }
```

now use `stopRecording(withOutput:` , instead of `exportClip(to:`

---

And more:

according to apple's doc

[stopRecording(withOutput:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/3588486-stoprecording)

> the movie is written to the specified output URL.

we need the `mp4` file